# When article can be left out for countable nouns

Tags: grammar, article

In German, it is quite common to see the article left out for countable nouns, e.g.,

> So gilt die Mietpreisbremse nicht überall, sondern nur in Gebieten mit "angespanntem Wohnungsmarkt". **Es ist Aufgabe** der Bundesländer, diese Gegenden festzulegen.

The noun "Aufgabe" is countable, but is used here without an article. In English, we would not say

> *It is task of the states

Is there a general rule of thumb on when the article can be left out for countable nouns?

Comment: In that case "Aufgabe" is not really something countable. It's kind of generic term; and it rather applies to "duty" than to "task". For that reason, no article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say that "Es ist Aufgabe ..." is somewhat idiomatic. There are some sentences where it is allowed and some, where it is totally forbidden.

It is allowed when generalizing and using plural:

> *Katzen* mögen *Mäuse*
>   Aber: *Die Katze* ist ein guter Jäger ("Die Katze" meaning "the species in general")

It is allowed when several nouns follow each other:

> Verbinden Sie Bildschirm und Computer. Schalten Sie dann Computer und Bildschirm an.
>   *Fenster* und *Türen* waren vernagelt

Proverbs or idiomatic phrases:

> Er hat Haus und Hof verloren (He lost house and farm => he lost everything)
>   Steter *Tropfen* hölt den Stein (Constant dripping wears away the stone)
>   von Amts wegen, an Bord, auf See...

On the other hand:

> *Ich habe Katze des Nachbarn gesehen.

Totally wrong.

Source: Duden, Die Grammatik, 8. Ausgabe, §384ff

Answer (score 6):

Abstrakta, die ganz allgemein eine Eigenschaft, einen Zustand oder Vorgang bezeichnen, stehen im Allgemeinen ohne Artikel:
Es ist *Aufgabe* der Länder. *Widerstand* ist zwecklos. Er braucht *Ruhe*. Sie hatte *Geduld*.

Weitere Fälle, in denen Substantive ohne Artikel stehen können, sind laut *Duden - Richtiges und gutes Deutsch*:

- Stoffsubstantive
- Zeitausdrücke mit Adjektiv, aber ohne Präposition; präpositionslose Wochentagsangaben
- feste Wendungen, Wortpaare und -gruppen, Aufzählungen, Sprichwörter
- angeführte Wörter, Kommandos, Ausrufe, Anrufe
- Über- und Aufschriften, Titel, Schlagzeilen, Anzeigen, Telegramme

Answer (score 0):

As to the question "article or omission of article", I think it is irrelevant whether a noun is countable or not - at least in German. I would say you can drop "der/die/das" if the information of "definiteness" does not have much weight. As to use of articles there is no rule of thumb. It is an idiomatic matter that varies from language to language.